# How to determine if a in-app subscription on Google Play has been renewed?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

The following documentation describes the result from querying the Google Play API about a subscription: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions#resource-representations

However, if a user cancels a subscription when there is still time left in the current period, will the cancelReason be empty or will it be 0? In other words, will the cancelReason flag stay empty until there is no time left in the current period, or will it change immediately on cancellation?

Answer (score 0):

> In other words, will the cancelReason flag stay empty until there is no time left in the current period, or will it change immediately on cancellation?

I think, the answer is "**it doesn't matter**", because [documentation says](https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html#practices):

> Query for subscription status **only at expiration** — Once your server has retrieved the expiration date of subscription tokens, it should not query the Google Play servers for the subscription status again **until the subscription is reaching or has passed the expiration date**. Typically, your servers would run a batch query each day to check the status of expiring subscriptions, then update the database.

In fact they can change it immediatly, but they don't guarantee this until the end of expiration time.